# Selenium set chrome binary only if binary is not in standard location

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Looking here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location

I see that we can set the chrome binary if it's in a non standard location like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
```

I have situation where one machine has the binary in a standard location but another doesn't. **Is there a way to check if the chrome binary is in the standard location?** That way I'll only set the binary if it's not in the standard location.

My current workaround is to use exceptions:

```
try {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
} catch (WebDriverException e) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
}
```

But I'm still **curious** how the chrome driver knows where the standard binary path is.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**: directly check in the non standard location, if there is a chrome binary file. You can use the code below:

```
File binaryFile = new File("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
    if(binaryFile.exists()){
        //binary file is not in standard location
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
    }
    else{
        //binary file is in standard location
    }
```

**Second solution**: You can use `System.getProperty("os.name")` to distinguish your two machines, if they have different OS. If they don't you can find other properties on this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
and use this code:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().equals("windows")){
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capability.setCapability("chrome.binary","/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
}
```

in second solution, I have supposed that you have different OS on your machine. This is the solution that I use. However it is more specific to my issue.

Comment: In my situation they both have the same OS. I was wondering **how chrome driver knows** where the default binary path is when we don't specify the binary. Maybe I can use the same method to determine if binary exist in the default path before specifying the binary path.

Comment: Have you tried to search Chrome binary on your machine, that has it placed in the standard location ?